# php $_GET - clarification

Tags: php, conditional-statements

So i have a form that when the user presses submit, the form throws them to a processing file and if any of those fields values dont validate, then that process form sends the user back to the page they came from. I thought it useful to add a message telling them whats wrong so.....

The form page (contact.php) for example is constructed like this (below)

```
<?php 
$errormssg = stripslashes(str_replace("'","",$_GET['errormssg']));
if($errormssg){
    echo $errormssg;    
} 
?>
<html>
<form fields here >
</html>
```

and the php process form is constructed more or less like this (below )

```
<?php 

<form validation code goes here and if it fails, then throws them back to form page exactly 
like this (below)

header("Location:contact.php?errormssg='You seem to have forgotten one of the fields'");



?>
```

The problem im getting is that, when i first load the contact page, i get an error which im going to assume is because when the contact page is first loaded, `$_GET['errormssg']` doesnt exist.

ive tried things like

```
if($_GET['errormssg']){
    echo $errormssg;
}
```

And still errors, am i going about this in the wrong way?

All im essentially trying to do is, that when contact page loads, the ONLY way that error message  is going to spit out a message is if the user got sent back from the processing form. So if the message exists then echo it in the designated area, else dont show anything.

How can i do this?? thanks in advanced.

Comment: Why is people so reluctant to post actual error messages?

Comment: You may already know this and have omitted it to keep the domain private, but `header("Location:"...)` should contain the full URL. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30

Comment: Voting to close this as "Unclear what you're asking" on the basis that you refuse to tell us what error messages you're actually seeing, even after being prompted once already.

Answer (score 5):

You need to check first if the value is defined or not :

```
if (isset($_GET) && isset($_GET['errormssg'])) {
    echo $_GET['errormssg'];
}
```

EDIT: According to MrCode $_GET is now always defined. It wasn't when I learnt PHP and never lost the habit since then, sorry for the confusion. You don't need the first part of the if

Comment: `isset($_GET)` is pointless. It is always set, however it may or may not contain any elements.

Comment: I did not know that. I updated my answer to reflect this, thanks!

Comment: As @MrCode points out, it's pointless. Even if `$_GET` didn't exist (which is not the case), `isset($_GET['errormssg'])` would be enough.

Comment: i know what he meant lol, i had put in tthe isset get errormessages. thanks all

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`if(isset($_GET['errormssg']))`

Answer (score 2):

if(isset($_GET['errormssg'])){

This should work :)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['errormsg']) {
   echo $_GET['errormsg'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have said, you need to check if the variable is set before trying to use it. PHP automatically issues an `Undefined index` notice if you try to access an array element  which is not set.

There are better solutions to your error message system. The drawbacks are that the user can essentially modify direct content on your page through the use of the query string. The first problem is it's vulnerable to XSS so you should pass the message through `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()` to prevent that. Even with no XSS, the user can still set content on your page which is undesirable.

The simplest solution is to use an error code in the URL instead of the whole message. In your PHP you can map error codes to messages. The benefit of this being, the user cannot tamper with the message content, but they can still change the code to produce different messages.

An even better solution would be to use a message queue system based on the session. This would work by storing an array for messages as a session variable. When you need to display a message, you simply add to the array. On your frontend, you can loop over the messages in the session array and output them, then (importantly) clear the array.

This would be better because it's completely isolated from the user, and it would work system or site wide, not just for your contact form. Below is a simple example.

```
// add a message if validation fails
MesssageManager::addMessage('You seem to have forgotten one of the fields');
```

On the frontend output the messages in an unordered list and clear them:

```
<html>

<?php echo MessageManager::getHTML(); MessageManager::clear(); ?>

</html>
```

The class could look something like

```
session_start();
class MessageManager
{
    public static function addMessage($message)
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['messages']))
        {
            $_SESSION['messages'][] = $message;
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['messages'] = array($message);
        }
    }

    public static function clear()
    {
        $_SESSION['messages'] = array();
    }

    public static function getHTML()
    {
        $h  = '<ul>';
        foreach($_SESSION['messages'] as $message)
        {
            $h .= '<li>' . htmlentities($message) . '<li>';
        }
        $h .= '</ul>';

        return $h;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I would like to address the original question.  As there are already answers for the obvious `isset()` .. I would like to point out that 1) You don't need to check for the existence of `$_GET` prior, it's just wasted code.  So the examples such as:

```
if(isset($_GET['errormsg']) {
  echo $_GET['errormsg'];
}
```

are indeed correct usage.  I would like to also point out you will get PHP Notices & Warnings **anytime** you use `$_GET['foo']` without it being initialized first.  So for example, this **will** produce a notice: (Note: In the below examples I changed "errormssg" to "errormsg", note the removal of the double "s")

```
$errormsg = stripslashes(str_replace("'","",$_GET['errormsg']));
if(isset($errormsg)) {
  echo $errmsg;
}
```

In fact, that code is very redundant, since unless the code changes, `$errmsg` will always be set.  To use this properly, you would want to say something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['errormsg'])) { 
   $errormsg = stripslashes(str_replace("'","",$_GET['errormsg']));
   echo $errormsg;
}
```

I would also like to point out the usage of `!empty()` as well.  `!empty()` is different than `isset()` that can be demonstrated with the following example:

```
$x = '';
if(isset($x)) { echo 'This will fire, since $x *is* set, just empty'; }
if(!empty($x)) { echo 'This will not fire, even though $x is set, it is empty'; }
```

Although for your example, it will only make unnoticeable differences more than likely.

Secondly, although not related directly to the original question, I would like to point out your use of `header()` and URLs is highly incorrect:

```
header("Location:contact.php?errormssg='You seem to have forgotten one of the fields'");
```

This is all wrong.  You **should** instead use something like this:

header("Location: contact.php?errormsg=" . urlencode("You seem to have forgotten one of the fields"));

Note the space between Location: and the URL.  Technically, this is **still** incorrect but will work.  The 100% proper way to do it (according to the RFC) would be to include the **full** URL in the header, such as:

```
header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com/contact.php?errormsg=" . 
  urlencode("You seem to have forgotten one of the fields"));
```

You will not need your `stripslashes()` if you URL escape/encode your data properly.